# How to use for each in multiple control?

Tags: vb.net, loops, checkbox, foreach

Im trying to clear all the field in textbox and uncheck all checkbox when the form on load

All my checkbox are inside TableLayoutPanel, but i have alot of TableLayoutPanel

Currently im using this method, but there is too many duplicate code

```
Private Sub ResetPage()      

    Dim ctrl As Control

    For Each ctrl In tlp_userInfo.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
            ctrl.Text = Nothing
        End If
        If TypeOf ctrl Is ComboBox Then
            ctrl.Text = Nothing
        End If
    Next

    For Each ctrl In tlp_chkb1.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
            DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox).Checked = False
        End If
    Next

    For Each ctrl In tlp_chkb2.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
            DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox).Checked = False
        End If
    Next

    For Each ctrl In tlp_chkb3.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
            DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox).Checked = False
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

is that any other way to uncheck all the checkbox in diffrent TableLayoutPanel?

Edited:

Finally i get it done, but i dont think this is a good idea if the form has so many layer.

```
        For Each ctrl_layer1 As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl_layer1 Is TableLayoutPanel Then
            For Each ctrl_layer2 As Control In ctrl_layer1.Controls
                If TypeOf ctrl_layer2 Is TableLayoutPanel Then
                    For Each ctrl_layer3 As Control In ctrl_layer2.Controls
                        If TypeOf ctrl_layer3 Is TableLayoutPanel Then
                            For Each ctrl_layer4 In ctrl_layer3.Controls
                                If TypeOf ctrl_layer4 Is TextBox Then
                                    ctrl_layer4.Text = ""
                                ElseIf TypeOf ctrl_layer4 Is ComboBox Then
                                    ctrl_layer4.Text = ""
                                ElseIf TypeOf ctrl_layer4 Is TabControl Then
                                    For Each ctrl_layer5 As Control In ctrl_layer4.controls
                                        If TypeOf ctrl_layer5 Is TabPage Then
                                            For Each ctrl_layer6 In ctrl_layer5.Controls
                                                If TypeOf ctrl_layer6 Is TableLayoutPanel Then
                                                    For Each ctrl_layer7 In ctrl_layer6.controls
                                                        If TypeOf ctrl_layer7 Is TableLayoutPanel Then
                                                            For Each ctrl_layer8 In ctrl_layer7.controls
                                                                If TypeOf ctrl_layer8 Is CheckBox Then
                                                                    DirectCast(ctrl_layer8, CheckBox).Checked = False
                                                                End If
                                                            Next
                                                        End If
                                                    Next
                                                End If
                                            Next
                                        End If
                                    Next
                                End If
                            Next
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: You should start  looping from `ctrl_layer3` only, what is the point of looping `ctrl_layer1` and `ctrl_layer2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through all `TableLayoutPanel` in your form and loop through `textboxes`,`checkboxes` in each `TableLayoutPanel`

```
   For Each ctrl_tlo As Control In Me.Controls
      If TypeOf (ctrl_tlo) Is TableLayoutPanel Then
         For Each ctrl As Control In ctrl_tlo.Controls
             If TypeOf (ctrl) Is TextBox Then
                 ctrl.Text = ""
             ElseIf TypeOf (ctrl) Is CheckBox Then
                 DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox).Checked = False
             End If
         Next
      End If
   Next
```

Comment: doesnt work, i use breakpoint to check during debug mode, the system cant find any textbox or checkbox when run until line 4

Comment: Does it passes through `TableLayoutPanel` ?

Comment: i guess i know whats the problem already, because i have another tablelayoutpanel inside the tablelayoutpanel...

Comment: @vbnewbie `Dim ctrlcount As Integer = TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count` use this and comment me the output

Comment: _i have another tablelayoutpanel inside the tablelayoutpanel_ > So you've two  options 1 is write an `elseif` condition for `TableLayoutPanel` and loop through controls in it.2 is bring controls from child `TableLayoutPanel`  to parent `TableLayoutPanel`

Comment: for my case, do you think this is a good idea if i write in this way? or any other suggestion?

Comment: @vbnewbie Nothing comes to mind atm apart from aforementioned two options

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Dim SetofPanels = {Name of your panels with comma between each controls}
For Each ctrl In SetofPanels 

If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
       ctrl.Text = Nothing
End If

If TypeOf ctrl Is ComboBox Then
       ctrl.Text = Nothing
End If

If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
       DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox).Checked = False
End If

Next
```

Comment: it doesnt work, im getting this error End of statement expected. red underline under comma

Comment: Do you want a code that will clear all controls in diff,. panel  in just one code?

Comment: yes, because i have more than 10 TableLayoutPanel with checkbox in that form

Comment: Pls see the edited post, try to go back to you tomorrow if this one doesnt work

Comment: still cant, nothing error, but text in textbox wont clear, checkbox wont uncheck